# Installing XML-RPC C++

Tags: apt, package-management, c++, xml

I am trying to install XML-RPC for C++, and it seems like [this library](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) is the most often used. However, when building it using `./config`, I get the error message:

> configure: ==>We are not building any client XML transport (see
>   earlier  messages explaining why), therefore WE WILL NOT BUILD THE
>   CLIENT LIBRARY.

which seems to be caused by:

> checking for curl-config... no configure: You don't appear to have
>   Curl installed (no working  curl-config in your command search path),
>   so we will not build the Curl  client XML transport checking whether
>   to build Curl client XML transport module... no

However, I've already install curl: `sudo apt-get install curl`, so I don't see why this is happening. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

I'm also just getting started, so if there's another library that is more widely used/supported, I'd like to know.

Comment: You probably need to install one of the curl **development** packages (`libcurl4-gnutls-dev`, `libcurl4-nss-dev`, or `libcurl4-openssl-dev` depending which implementation you prefer - or whichever the software demands).

Comment: @steeldriver, is there any dev package you would recommend?

Comment: @steeldriver, that did the trick. If you like, please submit your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the error. It was showing many things missing like:

```
autoconf
automake
makeinfo
```

and many others

I didn't know what to do so I started installing the missing things one by one.

But `makeinfo` was not there in the repository. I used `makeinfo` as a command in the terminal though I knew it was not installed. I knew that if an uninstalled command is given then system itself suggests for proper package installation. So I installed `texinfo` as suggested by the system for missing `makeinfo`. Still I was getting errors and I decided to install `libcurl`. I got this hint from @steeldriver's comment.

I just installed `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and everything worked fine for me.

Comment: Yep, libcurl4-gnutls-dev does the trick